# Using vim with taglist and ctags in OSX

Tags: c++, vim, taglist

I installed taglist and ctags for vim in OSX. It looks cool, but it's hard to use. For one thing, after I select a tag in the taglist window, it jumps to the code, but then I don't know how to get back to the taglist window to select another place to go to. How do you do that? What are some changes you recommend making so that this is easier to use?

Answer (score 3):

I am using the following configuration in my .vimrc :

```
" Taglist plugin mapping
noremap <silent> <Leader>t :TlistToggle<CR>

" Taglist plugin config
let Tlist_Use_Right_Window = 1
let Tlist_Inc_Winwidth = 0
let Tlist_WinWidth = 45
let Tlist_GainFocus_On_ToggleOpen= 1
let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd = 'ctags'
let Tlist_Show_One_File = 1
```

You can switch back and forth between code and list quickly with `<Leader>t` to display or hide the taglist window.
The other options are personal preferences only.

Comment: @z-buffer: Leader is a key that you can redefine. It is usually used to start (or lead) a complex key combination. See `:help Leader`. If you have not redefined it, by default it is the \ (backslash) key. I use `,`as a Leader so in my case the key combination is `,t`, by default it would be `\t`

Answer (score 1):

You can move between windows using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> and the movement keys <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>

Comment: Why does ctrl-w have to be pressed twice?

Comment: @z-buffer: All the window related commands are prefixed with `Ctrl+W`. For example, `Ctrl+W N` to create a new window, `Ctrl+W _` to expand the current window, etc. The regular "go to next window" command is `Ctrl+W Ctrl+W`, which makes it easy to type. For more information on Vim windows, see the [Vim window documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html).

Answer (score 0):

To go back after jumping to a tag, use <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd>. For more information on tag navigation, see [Browsing programs with tags](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags) on the Vim wiki.

Comment: Ok. I don't use the tag window thingy you described, but I use `Ctrl+]` to jump to the tag under the cursor. In *that* case, `Ctrl+T` should work to go back.

Answer (score 0):

`<C-w>p` lets you go back to the previous window.

And I recommend Xavier T.'s configuration.